# How to execute a parameterized fixture for only some of the parameters?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

From the official documentation, in the example about parametrizing fixtures:

> [Parametrizing fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures)
>
> Extending the previous example, we can flag the fixture to create two smtp_connection fixture instances **which will cause all tests using the fixture to run twice.**
>
> ```py
> @pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=["smtp.gmail.com", "mail.python.org"])
> def smtp_connection(request):
> ```

I wrote a parametrized fixture like the above example, but now my problem is I want to use the fixture in a different test function that should only execute once for one of the parameters...Like so:

```py
def my_test_function(smtp_connection)
    # I want this function to execute only once for the first or the second parameter...
```

So my question is: Can a test function use the fixture and be executed only for some parameters using [pytest API](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html)? Or is this use case already a mistake and should both the fixture or the test functions be implemented differently in such case? If so, what would conceptually be the correct design alternative?

I am looking for a programmatic solution that doesn't require using command-line flags when I run pytest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [indirect fixture parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) - in this case you would define the parameters you want to use in the test instead of the fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def smtp_connection(request):
    url = request.param
    ...

pytest.mark.parametrize("smtp_connection", ["smtp.gmail.com", "mail.python.org"], indirect=True)
def def my_test_function(smtp_connection):
    ...

pytest.mark.parametrize("smtp_connection", ["smtp.gmail.com"], indirect=True)
def def my_other_test_function(smtp_connection):
    ...
```

This will parametrize the fixture with each of the parameters you provide in the list for a specific test. You can read the parameter from `request.param` as shown above.

Of course, if you have many tests that use the same parameters you are probably better off using specific fixtures instead.